# Google Sheets associate unique

Tags: google-sheets, unique

I have 1000+ items (Game Names) in Sheet1  with some duplicates. In Sheet2 i use "unique" function to remove the duplicates and get them sorted alphabetically. Next to each record (2nd column) i assign Publisher values.

The problem is that if I add a new record in Sheet1, the record will be added in Sheet2 but the values from 2nd column are staying in place without matching or following the original content. I believe the issue appears because sorting is applied

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDKMi.png)
[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9nyD.png)

So if i add a new entry "Abacus" in Sheet1, it will sort alphabetically again in sheet2 but publishers value will remain in place they will not follow the sorting

Comment: Are you able to attach (a copy of) the Google Sheets Spreadsheet?

Comment: you should maintain a simplified database with publisher names and values, and then call the values in sheet2

Comment: When only a screenshot is attached. It's like asking for answers to create a sheet that they have to fill in themselves and then come up with the solution. Please make it easy for people to help you. Thank you.

Comment: screenshots added.